# Are php float return type declarations supposed to override output of a function or method?

Tags: php

Came across this and haven't seen it before. Basically using php's return type declaration overrides the precision of the output on floats. Currently using php 7.4 on this specific instance.

This app specifically has a really high floating point precision, set at 20.

Just an example of the behavior.

```
<?php 
function clean_number($input) : float {

    return number_format($input,2);

}

$number = 55.36643455;

echo clean_number($number);
```

My expectation would be an output of: 55.37

The actual output is: 55.369999999999997442

I don't see any mention of this in php docs. Is this the intended behavior because it breaks functions that might return float values of a different precision. For now removing the type declaration fixes it, but since this is being used more frequently now, seems like it could be problematic.

Comment: [number_format returns a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), so your return type is really converting the string back to a float, breaking the precision.

Comment: Yep, that would be it.

Answer (score 0):

`number_format()` returns a string, formatted per the specification. Your function is asking to return a `float` so PHP coerces the string back to a float, losing the precision.

If you need to maintain the formatted version, retain the `string` when you return it.

i.e.

```
<?php 
function clean_number($input) : string {

    return number_format($input,2);

}

$number = 55.36643455;

echo clean_number($number); // 55.37
```

See https://3v4l.org/sHcbT

Answer (score 0):

No, PHP float return type declarations are not supposed to override the output of a function or method.

Return type declarations in PHP allow you to specify the type of value that a function or method should return. If a function or method declares a return type of float, it means that it should return a floating-point number value.

However, the return type declaration does not affect the actual output of the function or method. The output of a function or method is determined by its implementation, not its return type declaration.

For example, consider the following PHP function:

```
function divide($a, $b): float {
    return $a / $b;
}
```

This function declares a return type of float, which means that it should return a floating-point number. However, if you call the function with arguments 10 and 2, it will output 5, which is an integer. This is because the output of the function is determined by its implementation (in this case, the division operation), not its return type declaration.

So, in summary, PHP float return type declarations do not override the output of a function or method. They simply indicate the type of value that the function or method should return.